# Controlling the RTK Query API call for optimized infinite scrolling in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, rtk-query

I want to get a solid example code for optimized infinite scrolling with Lazy rtk query pagination API.

I tried:

```
const [getImages, { data: images, isLoading: imageLoading }] = useLazyGetImagesQuery();

 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    getImages(pageNumber);
    setData((prev) => [...new Set([...prev, ...images])]);
  }, [pageNumber]);

  console.log({ data });
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const { scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight } = document.documentElement;
    if (
      scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight * 0.8 &&
      imageLoading === false
    ) {
      setPageNumber((prevPageNumber) => prevPageNumber + 1);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

Which is actualling calling data for every scroll both up and down. I am not sure actually how to controll it. When to stop this Api calling in rtk lazy query and how to stop it?

Comment: You may want to look into using the `IntersectionObserver` for this type of behavior. It may fit in better with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the pagination APIs, you can find out if this is the last page (with the `next` property in response or something else).
So you can use that condition before calling `setPageNumber((prevPageNumber) => prevPageNumber + 1);` and can check whether you have reached to end of the pages or not.